# triggering events "over the wire" in .net

Tags: c#, .net, networking, remoting

I need a way to trigger events on remote processes "over the wire" and pass parameters (xml serialization, whatever). I want to be able to do things like this.

```
foreach(childClient c in clientList)
{
    MyEvent += c.EventHandler;
}

MyEvent("param");
```

what technologies are good for this? WCF?

This is a small deployment in house software project so minimal overhead in design is a plus, doesn't have to be "fast" and won't handle large amounts of traffic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this, but WCF is the best match for .NET code.  If you  are in-house then hopefully firewalls, etc aren't too much of a concern, and you can use the NET.TCP bindings which are full duplex.  You want to read up on [callback contracts](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx).

There are a number of examples out there, such as [this one](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm).

Comment: my biggest issue with WCF so far has been the "IS" side of things... I have issues with configuration.